# How do I loop a switch function in C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, for-loop, random, switch-statement

I've written a code so you can roll a dice but I want the dice to flash different sides of it before ending on its final side. When using a switch in a `for` loop, the switch doesn't seem to work. This is what I have so far.

```
        Random r = new Random();

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) 
        {
            Thread.Sleep(1000);

            foreach (Control x in this.Controls)
            {
                if (x is PictureBox && x.Tag.ToString() == "Dice")
                { x.Visible = false; }
            }

            int rInt = r.Next(1, 7);

            switch (rInt)
            {
                case 1: Dice1.Visible = true; break;
                case 2: Dice2.Visible = true; break;
                case 3: Dice3.Visible = true; break;
                case 4: Dice4.Visible = true; break;
                case 5: Dice5.Visible = true; break;
                case 6: Dice6.Visible = true; break;
            }

            Console.WriteLine(rInt);
        }
```

The output in the console shows that it does take 10 random numbers yet `switch` doesn't seem to execute except for the last one.

Does anybody know if I'm doing something wrong?

Comment: Do yourself a favor and `PictureBox[] allDice = { Die1, Die2, Die3, Die4, Die5, Die6 };`  Now your foreach can iterate that array instead of `Controls`, and your switch can go away.

Comment: Step by step, you set all your `Dice`s' `Visible` to `true`. But who will hide them?

Comment: @BenVoigt At first I had something like that, but since this is a school assignment, I had to use switch.

Comment: @RomanRyzhiy They only become visible if ```rInt``` matches that number. At the start of the loop, all dices are hidden again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add a call to `Refresh()` method on the form or the container control at the end of the loop else the loop is executed without changing the UI (the UI thread is "blocked" by the loop) :

```
for ( int i = 0; i < 10; i++ )
{
  ...
  Refresh(); // or Panel.Refresh()
}
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.refresh

Perhaps you can also use the name of the picture box instead of the `Tag` to have a better and cleaner code because using the `Tag` here is not really usefull:

```
if ( x is PictureBox && x.Name.StartsWith("Dice") )
```

Having names as Dice1, Dice2... for example.

You can also add an `Application.DoEvents()` for example if you want to add a button to stop the loop with a conditional variable :

```
for ( int i = 0; i < 10; i++ )
{
  Application.DoEvents();
  if ( CancelRequired ) break;
  ...
  Refresh();
}
```

Or use multithreading if needed...

Answer (score 0):

> Thread.Sleep(1000);

This blocks the thread.  It does not permit it to do other work such as painting.

Instead, use `await Task.Delay(1000)` or a Timer callback.